# Don't fire onchange event if its called from a specific function?

Tags: jquery, onchange, preventdefault

I have a drop-down which is associated with `onchange` event.

```
<select id="code" class="form-control">
  <option value="0"> Select Code </option>
  <option value="1"> 3456741 </option>
  <option value="2"> 1741100 </option>
</select>
```

I am using select2 customization:

```
$("#code").select2();
```

My `onchange` event:

```
$("#code").change(function(){
    getDetails($(this).val());
}
```

I have a button with click event:

```
$(".btnCancel").on("click", function (e) 
{
   $("#code").val(parseInt(myValue)).trigger("change");
}
```

When I click cancel button, it calls `onchange` event. I want to prevent change event, however I want drop-down to show the value which I am selecting for this function but do not call change event which is associated with this drop-down. I already tried following:

```
e.preventDefault();
e.stopPropagation();
```

Comment: So why do you trigger the change event then?

Comment: Otherwise it's not showing the selected value in drop-down